# Issue with contract verification on Etherscan

Tags: tokens, ropsten, etherscan, contract-verification

I have successfully deployed a new token contract on Etherscan Ropsten Network using metamask. I see my contract listed as "Unverified" so I followed the process given on https://ropsten.etherscan.io/verifyContract to get it verified but was unsuccessful with a message as follows:

[image: CWF Verification]

There are no changes done to the code. Kindly, suggest me what i'm missing here?

Other Information:

- Contract Address: 0x0890fe640F27a74665E1Fdb5A0c532e154B7020e
- Token Name: CWF Currency
- Token Symbol: CWF

Comment: This feature compares the byte codes of the published smart contract and the one you uploaded for verification. Have you changed anything meanwhile?

Comment: No i haven't changed anything at all! That's what amazed me.

Comment: I also have same problem like that.but i dont know which compiler version is using in my contract.
can someone help me.i will show the code.![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRBfI.png)

Comment: Hi there. If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//ethereum.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to verified contract with Optimization Disabled with out add ABI code

Comment: Where exactly is this "Optimization Disabled" setting located? Somewhere on etherscan web site? Or in metamask?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed your source code, the only possible reason seems to be that Metamask and Etherscan use different compiler versions.

Comment: Yes, thank you for mentioning that. I corrected my mistake but didn't got any success until i disabled "Optimization". It's now resolved. :)